# How to use an object passed as a function parameter?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, axios

I'm setting a CRUD vue app that communicates with an api via axios. I'm having problems trying to set the PATCH function

I use a mixin providing this method

```
axiosPatch (url, body, msg = 'Failed to update data to server') {
      return this.$axios.patch(url, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.token
        },
        body
      })
        .catch(() => console.log(msg))
    }
```

and I call it somewhere else:

```
this.axiosPatch('/people/' + this.person.id, { body: { person: { first_name: 'test' } } })
```

At the api side I this output:

```
Started PATCH "/people/712" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-07-19 00:26:54 +0300
Processing by PeopleController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"headers"=>{"Content-Type"=>"application/json", "Authorization"=>"Bearer ey...w"}, "body"=>{"body"=>{"person"=>{"first_name"=>"test"}}}, "id"=>"712", "person"=>{}}
```

I expected the output to be

```
...
Parameters: {"headers"=>{"Content-Type"=>"application/json", "Authorization"=>"Bearer ey...w"}, "person"=>{"first_name"=>"test"}, "id"=>"712"}
```

any help please?

**EDIT**

approach #1:

```
this.axiosPatch('/people/' + this.person.id, { person: { first_name: 'test' } })

axiosPatch (url, { body }, msg = 'Failed to update data to server') {
  // console.log(body) <-- this outputs 'undefined'     
  return this.$axios.patch(url, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.token
    },
    body
  }).catch(() => console.log(msg))
}

API output:
Started PATCH "/people/712" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-07-19 00:26:54 +0300
Processing by PeopleController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"headers"=>{"Content-Type"=>"application/json", "Authorization"=>"Bearer ey...w"}, "id"=>"712", "person"=>{}}
```

approach #2:

```
this.axiosPatch('/people/' + this.person.id, { body: { person: { first_name: 'test' } } })

axiosPatch (url, body, msg = 'Failed to update data to server') {
  // console.log(body) <-- this outputs the Object correctly     
  return this.$axios.patch(url, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.token
    },
    body: body.body
  }).catch(() => console.log(msg))
}

API output:
Started PATCH "/people/712" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-07-19 00:26:54 +0300
Processing by PeopleController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"headers"=>{"Content-Type"=>"application/json", "Authorization"=>"Bearer ey...w"}, "body"=>{"person"=>{"first_name"=>"test"}}, "id"=>"712", "person"=>{}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
this.axiosPatch('/people/' + this.person.id, { person: { first_name: 'test' } })

axiosPatch (url, body, msg = 'Failed to update data to server') {
  var o = Object.assign({
    { headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.token
      }
    },
    body
  )
  return this.$axios.patch(url, o).catch(() => console.log(msg))
}
```

and I get what I expected.
Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are adding an Object with the key body, you can fix it by adding `{body}` to your param list. This will give you body var with `{ person: ... }`

```
axiosPatch (url, {body}, msg = 'Failed to update data to server') {
      return this.$axios.patch(url, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.token
        },
        body
      })
        .catch(() => console.log(msg))
    }
```

Also, you can remove the body key in the argument you pass to axiosPatch.

Or you can do you can:

```
axiosPatch (url, body, msg = 'Failed to update data to server') {
      return this.$axios.patch(url, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.token
        },
        body: body.body
      })
        .catch(() => console.log(msg))
    }
```

Comment: I changed the axiosPatch function and removed the body key in the argument when I call it. Now, the output is more like it but not what I expected: "person"=>{}. Why does it pass an empty {}? I expected "person"=>{"first_name"=>"test"}

Comment: If you get an empty object, check if after your change you have removed the person data.

Comment: the person data is still there. I only removed the body key. I noticed that if I call a console.log(body) in the axiosPatch function I get an "undefined". I also tested the 2nd approach (body: body.body): the console.log outputs the object correctly but it outputs "body"=>{"person"=>{"first_name"=>"test"}}

Comment: Edit your question an add the modifications and data passed